# PGP: Can I just upload my public part of encryption sub key to PGP server?

Tags: pgp

I'm a little bit confused here, since the best practice suggests that main key should be completely offline, so which key should I upload to the public directory?

Here's what I have:

- main key (sign only)
- subkey#1 (sign)
- subkey#2 (encryption)
- subkey#3 (authentication).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best practices are to keep your primary *private* key offline. Your public key is *required* to be available, as all subkeys, user IDs (and thus certifications) are bound to it.

As you do not upload private keys to key servers anyway, you do not have to care about offline keys at all. You *have* to upload the primary public key, but could choose from the subkeys (depending on which you want to be available).